# Javascript new Date() timezone on Chrome console is 'diferent' to my pc timezone

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, timezone

I am debugging in chrome console and it shows timezone GMT+3, BUT my pc has timezone GMT-3 (argentina). Why Chrome does not respect my pc timezone?
I reinstall chrome but no success, how can I change timezone in chrome from GMT+3 to GMT-3

pd: Firefox is working correctly (GMT-3) and I am not using any google acount.
So, Why Chrome does not respect my pc timezone? and How can a change chrome timezone? Is
it possible? thanks

[image]

Comment: There are Chrome extensions that change its timezone. Otherwise it should use the OS timezone.

Comment: Please give the output of `Intl.DateTimeFormat().resolvedOptions().timeZone` and `navigator.userAgent`.  If on Windows, please also give the output of `tzutil /g` from a command prompt.

Comment: (Also, hard to say without those details, but you might be experiencing [this bug](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1168528))